# Despite using isset() still geting Notice: Undefined variable: ScdTime in C:\wamp\...\AppointRequest2.php on line 25

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm also getting this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' , , '',128745)' at line 1
```

I've already used `isset()` and `!empty()` functions. All my variables are being declared before being used. I've also searched a lot and still couldn't solve this problem. PLease please help me. I'm stuck here. Any help will be of great use to me. Thanks.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

$authorized = false;
session_start();
include('config.php');

if(isset($_SESSION['crnumbers']) && isset($_SESSION['passwords']))
{
    $authorized = true;

    if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && !empty($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $ScdDate = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ScdDate']); 
        $ScdMonth = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ScdMonth']); 
        $ScdYear = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ScdYear']); 
        $DName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DName']) ; 
        $ScdTime = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ScdTime']); 
    }

    $crnumber = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['crnumbers']);

    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO schedule(ScdDate,ScdMonth,ScdYear,ScdTime,crnumber,DName)VALUES($ScdDate, $ScdMonth, $ScdYear, '$ScdTime', $crnumber, '$DName')");

    if(!$sql) 
    {
        die('There is some error. Damn it! ' .mysql_error());
    }

    header("location: http://localhost/Alok/Health%20Care%20Project\GUI\patientGUI2.php");

}

else if(!$authorized)
{
    header("location:");
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: If $_POST is set, you are escaping. But the SQL query gets sent every time. Do indent your code better - it is a mess in this posting, and probably also in the original.

Comment: But your not doing `isset($_POST['ScdTime'])` so you misunderstand the concept, **ALL** those $_POST vars need checkingbefore using, also [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Now I've done `isset($_POST[''])` for each of them. Still getting the same error. And sorry for the indenting mess. It was my first ever question and I'm getting things here. Now any suggestions?  @Sven

Comment: What do you mean "despite using isset"? You didn't check the variable in question.

Comment: You don't understand the purpose of the isset check. If the necessarily variables aren't set then blindly plowing through the mysql_query anyway three lines later like a car without tires is not going to work. If the variable are set, use them; if they're not, either substitute default values or don't do the query. Note also your query has a SQL injection vulnerability on the date, month, and year variables because they're not quoted (something which using PDO would prevent).

Comment: The data is being sent from a form. And all these variables are being set with respective values. I used `isset()` as a precaution. And the date, month and year variables are of the type int. This is why I didn't quote them, similarly CR Number.

Comment: @user2546672 They're not ints, they're strings. Do `var_dump($ScdDate);` and it will tell you it's a string. **All** variables that come through $_POST are strings. In any case, it's meaningless to use mysql_real_escape_string on a value that you're not putting inside quotes, because if the strings did contain something that needed escaping, it would be a SQL syntax error because it wouldn't be inside quotes.

Comment: @Boann Well, thank you very much. My knowledge of php is nascent and I'm very thankful for this info.

Comment: @user2546672 You're welcome. Sorry if I seem short-tempered by the way; am having a bad day.

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as it seems, is that the variables used in the INSERT query aren't containing valid data and might be set to empty and therefore breaking the INSERT query.

There are 2 options that you can use here:

A] Try to use the below assignment syntax; it sets the given value if it is not-empty otherwise sets it to 0

```
$ScdDate = (!empty($_POST['ScdDate'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ScdDate']) : 0;
$ScdMonth = (!empty($_POST['ScdMonth'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ScdMonth']): 0;
$ScdYear = (!empty($_POST['ScdYear'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ScdYear']) : 0;
$DName = (!empty($_POST['DName'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['DName']) : '';
$ScdTime = (!empty($_POST['ScdTime'])) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ScdTime']) : '';
```

B] Enclose all your values in single-quotes in the query

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO schedule(ScdDate,ScdMonth,ScdYear,ScdTime,crnumber,DName)VALUES('$ScdDate', '$ScdMonth', '$ScdYear', '$ScdTime', '$crnumber', '$DName')");
```

Hope the above helps!

By the way, the error given in the question isn't perhaps in sync with the query; the last value in the query is $DName enclosed in single quotes but the last value in the error isn't enclosed in single-quotes. I might be incorrect though ;-)

Comment: It's not A] or B], it's both. He needs to do both those things.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be because looking at the original INSERT query it seems that some integer field is set as blank and therefore breaks the query. So, if the coder ensures that these blank values are avoided (as suggested in [A]), the error should not show. Otherwise, enclose all values in single-quotes in the query to avoid two adjacent commas (as suggested in [B])

Comment: OK I did both. Now I'm not getting any earlier error yet the whole session is redirected to the the second URL, as if the session is not getting registered. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ummm, that perhaps might be because there is a redirect statement at the end of your code

Comment: Yes, I get it. But why the first redirect statement is not working? Why the session is not getting registered? And the insert query not taking place? Please help, I'd be really thankful.

Comment: Hard to explain but perhaps you'll have to validate this on your own. Please confirm the contents of $_SESSION by doing a vardump() or print_r(). It might also make sense to look at the contents of $_POST. I guess the issue might be elsewhere since the INSERT query was running earlier perhaps, no?

Answer (score 0):

You're checking `$_POST["submit"]` existence, but not `$_POST["ScdTime"]`'s. That's why the notice remains. Concerning your MySQL error, the comments let on your question quite answer it.

You need to use isset() on every variable that might be used later in the code :)

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) &&
   isset($_POST['ScdDate']) && 
   isset($_POST['ScdMonth']) &&
   isset($_POST['ScdYear']) &&
   isset($_POST['DName']) &&
   isset($_POST['ScdTime']))
      // We're good!
```

Comment: Still I'm getting the same error of undefined variable. All in the mysql_query() line. Earlier it was on line 20 now 5 lines later in line 25 Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

The correct way would be:
if(array_key_exists('crnumbers', $_POST)) {}

Also make sure you check ALL array keys. That's causing the second error.